# Get dimensions after setLayoutParams in Android

Tags: android, layout, view

In Android, after a call to [View.setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), how can you find out the dimensions (width & height) and position (x & y coordinates) of a view?

If I query these properties immediately after `setLayoutParams` they return invalid values.

According to the documentation, [View.onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) is called after the size of the view is changed. Does this means that I have to subclass the widget whose dimensions I want to query, override `onSizeChanged` and notify my activity of the change?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself, but as long as you've added the view as a child and called invalidate() after you've set the layoutParams, i think you should be able to determine the width and height.